# how to show vector features in OpenLayers after hiding it?

Tags: vector, filtering, openlayers

I did change some features style (through check-boxes) using style property :

```
var features = layer.features;

for( var i = 0; i < features.length; i++ ) {
  //features[i].style = { visibility: 'hidden' };
    features[i].style = 'none'; 
}

layer.redraw();
```

Now if I check the box again, it supposed to display again but nothing happens!
I tried:

```
     features[i].style = 'block'; 
OR
     features[i].style = 'delete';
```

then redraw the layer.. but this doesn't work

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// set style
    features[i].style = null;
// or
    features[i].style = {display:'none'};

// redraw feature
layer.drawFeature(features[i]);
```

Comment: style = { display: 'none' } worked. I tried it on openlayers version 2.13, to display again, I set style = ''